# Read resource file using StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync defined in an assembly

Tags: c#, uwp

I know I can read a resource file defined (build action set to content) in the main UWP app using the following API.

```
var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
               new Uri($"ms-appx:////{fileName}"));
```

This works as long the file/resource is defined in the main application. I am not able to make it work with a resource/file specified in an assembly which is then referenced by the main UWP application.

What is the best way to read a resource file from the assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
           new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/Your.Base.AssemblyName;component/YourResDictionaryFolder/Dictionary1.xaml"));
```

`Your.Base.AssemblyName` = Dll name / Another assembly name

`YourResDictionaryFolder` = Folder where you created your ResourceDictionary / sub folder

`Dictionary1.xaml` = File /resource name which you need to access

Answer (score 0):

For a UWP application:

```
 var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
       new Uri($"pack://ms-appx:///YourAssemblyName/YourResourceFolder/Filename.png"));
```